# Custom Wix Login not working after publishing

Tags: javascript, velo

I have create a custom login page in wix. Dev Mode testing is working fine, but after publishing it is not working when i check the inspect console below error is shown --

```
Query error: Error: WDE0053: Internal wixData error: Unknown error.
```

I have used custom CMS (public access) to store username password data.

```
import wixUsers from 'wix-users';
import wixData from 'wix-data';
import wixLocation from 'wix-location';

export function loginButton_click(event) {
  // Retrieve the entered username and password
  const username = $w('#usernameInput').value;
  const password = $w('#passwordInput').value;

  // Query the custom CMS collection for a matching record
  wixData.query('Student')
    .eq('username', username)
    .eq('password', password)
    .find()
    .then(results => {
      // If a matching record is found
      if (results.items.length > 0) {
        const student = results.items[0];

        console.log("student= ",student.username);

        // Log in the user
        wixUsers.applySessionToken(student._id)
          .then(() => {
            // Redirect to the employee portal page
            console.log("Redirect to studentportal ");
            wixLocation.to('/student-portal');
          })
          .catch(error => {
              console.log("Redirect Error");
            console.error('Login error:', error);
          });
      } else {
          console.log("Invalid username or password");
        // Display an error message for invalid credentials
        $w('#errorMessage').text = 'Invalid username or password';
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("Query Error");
      console.error('Query error:', error);
    });
}
```

In Wix Dev Mode login is working fine. but after publishing it is not working.

After some time I'm not getting WIX error. It seems like that is related to network issue in WIX. But, I'm getting below error instead --

> Login error:
> Object { errorCode: -20100, errorDescription: "Internal Server Error [request-id: 1690095981.73647962236214155]", success: false,
> payload: null }    ​
> errorCode: -20100
> errorDescription: "Internal Server Error [request-id: 1690095981.73647962236214155]"
> ​
> payload: null
> ​success: false
> ​: Object { … }
> feature-telemetry-wix-code-sdk.2f153b43.chunk.min.js:1:9305

Answer (score 0):

Do you have password protected your site? Then custom login and register don´t work for some reason. Turn that of and there is no problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35797368)